# VBA to produce the same page "x" amount of times

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word, I've created a template for a payment coupon book. So far I've written some code to load an input box/user form upon opening the word file. The user inputs stuff like name, payment date, payment amount, etc. After hitting submit, the user input is automatically entered into the template in the appropriate fields. I'm using bookmarks to do this.

My last piece of the puzzle is this: I need it to produce however many coupons that the user defines in one of my input boxes. Each coupon would have the same information. The only difference is the coupon ID needs to auto-increment to be a unique ID.

Think of this like producing a virtual checkbook almost. Your name, address, etc is all the same. The check number is different. This program is essentially asking how many checks you want.

Also, if this would be easier in Excel or even creating a form in Adobe please let me know. This was the only way I knew how to do it.

Feel free to ask any questions. Hope this makes sense.

Code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()


Dim flName As Range
Set flName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("flName").Range

    flName.Text = Me.firstNameTxt.Value

Dim acctNumber As Range
Set acctNumber = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("acctNumber").Range
    acctNumber.Text = Me.accountNumberTxt.Value

Dim trailerNumber As Range
Set trailerNumber = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("trailerNumber").Range
    trailerNumber.Text = Me.trailerTxt.Value

Dim DueDate As Range
Set DueDate = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("dueDate").Range
    DueDate.Text = Me.dueDateTxt.Value

Dim PaymentAmount As Range
Set PaymentAmount = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("paymentAmount").Range
    PaymentAmount.Text = Me.paymentAmountTxt.Value

Unload Me


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Comment: Just edited my op. Not much to it currently. I'm also wondering if I should have an input box in Excel, have it fill down the information however many times the user wants, then maybe have it create some sort of mail merge off of that instead of trying to write code to make it produce multiple pages.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1096117-vba-produce-same-page-x-amount-times.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

A fairly common approach is to use a mailmerge, where you'd have an Excel worksheet as the data source and a Word mailmerge main document attached to that. The numbering column in Excel would perhaps have no more than single cell for the input of a number, and the cells on subsequent rows would simply increment that. When completing the merge, simply choose how many record to process. Your description suggests you might need an Excel workbook where you can keep a permanent record of the names, payment dates, payment amounts, coupon #s, etc., all of which can be processed as part of the mailmerge. For the basics, see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705

For a variety of macro-based approaches for simple Word form replication, see:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/12959-sequential-document-numbering.html#post34477
http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/12641-sequential-print-numbering.html#post33829http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/35106-printing-multiple-copies-docm-word-pdf-saving.html#post113655